# Entity Framework 4 changes my table names when I do "Generate Database from model"

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm doing some simple things with EF4 and inheritance before I start the real work. I have tried it many ways and I can't fix this.

I have two tables:

- reporting_Items (ItemId,etc)
- reporting_DataItems (ItemId,etc)

I need to keep the prefixes in the database tables because of coding convention.

Then I want to have the maped entities with the names Item and DataItem, and DataItem inherits from Items.

I did Database First and created the tables, but I removed the ItemId key from reporting_DataItems.

Then I generated the model from the database. It created the entities:

- reporting_Item
- reporting_DataItems

which I renamed to Item and DataItem respectively. Then I created the inheritance relation between DataItem and Item.

So up to this point I have the entities named like I want and the tables named like I want, plus the inheritance.
The problem is that if now I run Generate Database from Model it deletes all the tables and creates them with this names:

- Items
- Items_DataItem

Is there any way to acchieve what I want to do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either database first (generated model from database or model first (generate database from model). Combining them is not supported because when you use model first it doesn't use information about your original database. It uses its own conventions to name tables and it expects that you are going to use that new table names instead of old ones. Conventions can be changed but it means changing .tt template used to generate SQL.

So if you have existing database and you want to use it, never use Generate Database from model because this tool is not for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what is not clear for me is what I do if I do Database First, then I do some tweaking in the model for instance to add the inheritance relation, and then if in the future I want to do modifications in the database how do I do it without losing the inheritance tweaking? For instance in the book "Entity Framework 4.0 Recipes" to create class inheritance from database related tables it advices to remove from the model the 1..* relation and add a inheritance relation.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as answer because I think you are right in terms of doing DB First and then breaking things with Generating DB from Model. I still have the doubt of doing DB First, tweaking the model (adding inheritance for instance) and then making changes in the db. I think the model tweakings will be lost when updating the model from db, and probably those tweakings will need to be done again.

Comment: If you make changes in database you must use "Update model from database". That will push changes into your model - most of your manual edits in model should be maintained but there are some situation when your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, now things are clear. Thank you for your help indeed :)